# Form a table from two tables with quantity manipulation

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables: item & job_item.
The table item has `item_id` as primary key, while job_item has a composite key (`item_id` & `job_id`).

[image]
[image]

I want to to get a a result like:

[image]

Where the `remaining_quantity` is: `item.quantity – sum(job_item.quantity)`, and if this equals zero I don’t want to show this specific item_id record.
My try:

```
SELECT `item`.`item_id` , `item_name` , `item_brand` ,  `item`.`quantity` - sum(  `job_item`.quantity` ) AS remaining_quantity
FROM `item` , `job_item` 
WHERE `job_item`.`item_id` = `item`.`item_id`;
```

But this shows wrong results and only always one record.

Comment: When you run your query what is the result you get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have unique `item_id` in your `item` table you just need to group by columns from `item` table and add a having clause to discard results with `remaining_quantity = 0`:

```
select
  i.item_id, i.item_name, i.item_brand, 
  i.quantity - sum(ji.quantity) as remaining_quantity
from item i
join job_item ji on i.item_id = ji.item_id
group by i.item_id, i.item_name, i.item_brand, i.quantity 
having i.quantity - sum(ji.quantity) <> 0
```

Result:

```
 item_id | item_name  | item_brand  | remaining_quantity
---------+------------+-------------+-------------------
      22 | dummy name | dummy brand |                39
```

Note:

- please use explicit `JOIN` syntax, don't do it the old-fashioned way in `WHERE` clause

*Edit per request in comments:*

If you need to deal with case where there is no matching row in `job_item` table, then change the join to a `LEFT JOIN` and apply `coalesce` over the `sum` so that it will return 0 instead of NULL value:

```
select
  i.item_id, i.item_name, i.item_brand,
  i.quantity - coalesce(sum(ji.quantity),0) as remaining_quantity
from item i
left join job_item ji on i.item_id = ji.item_id
group by i.item_id, i.item_name, i.item_brand, i.quantity
having i.quantity - coalesce(sum(ji.quantity),0) <> 0
```

Comment: Thanks Kamil, but this will not work if the item_id doesn't exist in job_item table? I think you didn't consider this case?

Comment: By doing JOIN directly in the WHERE clause you have defined an INNER JOIN (short: JOIN). If you need to deal with this case I've edited my answer to include it.

Answer (score 0):

Try with **`JOIN`**

```
SELECT I.item_id, I.item_name, I.item_brand, (I.quantity - J.Qty) AS remaining_quantity
FROM item I JOIN (SELECT item_id AS itm, SUM(quantity) Qty 
                  FROM job_item Group BY item_id) J ON J.item_id = I.item_id;
```

Comment: Thanks Kumar, but you also didn't  didn't consider this case where id_item is not available in job_item table